# Powershell: Get AzureRM automation schedule recurrence info

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, schedule

I'm doing some inventory trying to gather all my start/stop VM schedules from Azure.
I'm strugling with extracting the days selected for weekly recurrence schedules.
I can extract all the data from single schedules with:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription <name>
$schedule = Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName <name)-ResourceGroupName <name> -Name <name>
```

And then get all the days:

```
$schedule.WeeklyScheduleOptions.DaysOfWeek -join ","
```

Which outputs: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday

But if I loop through all my subscriptions and build a psobject
with all schedule data this data comes up empty:

```
$AzSubs = Get-AzureRmSubscription

$objs = @()
foreach ($AzSub in $AzSubs){

    Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $AzSub.Name | Select-AzureRmSubscription
    $azAutAccs = Get-AzureRmAutomationAccount 
    foreach ($azAutAcc in $azAutAccs){
        $AzAutScheds = Get-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $azAutAcc.AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $azAutAcc.ResourceGroupName
        $AzAutScheds = $AzAutScheds | where{$_.IsEnabled -eq "True"}
        foreach ($AzAutSched in $AzAutScheds){

        $DOW = $azAutSched.WeeklyScheduleOptions.DaysOfWeek -join "," | out-string
        $DOM = $azAutSched.MonthlyScheduleOptions.DaysOfMonth -join "," | out-string

            $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{

            SchedName = $AzAutSched.Name
            LastModifiedTime = (get-date ([DateTime]::Parse($AzAutSched.LastModifiedTime)) -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm (zzz)")
            IsEnabled = $AzAutSched.IsEnabled
            AutomationAccount = $azAutAcc.AutomationAccountName
            ResourceGroup = $azAutAcc.ResourceGroupName
            NextRun = ([DateTime]::Parse($azAutSched.NextRun))
            StartTime = (get-date ([DateTime]::Parse($azAutSched.StartTime)) -Format "HH:mm (zzz)")
            TimeZone = $azAutSched.TimeZone
            Interval = $azAutSched.Interval
            Frequency = $azAutSched.Frequency
            WeekSchedule = $DOW
            MonthSchedule = $DOM

            }

            $objs += $obj
            }

        }
    }
$objs | sort SchedName | ft -Property SchedName,LastModifiedTime,StartTime,TimeZone,Interval,Frequency,WeekSchedule,MonthSchedule
```

Then my table ends up with just blank columns for WeekSchedule/MonthSchedule.

I have tried different combos of leaving out the out-string parameter, leaving out the join, setting the property directly in the property line, and as quoted building the variable above the object and referencing it on the property line. None of them work.

Anyone can shed some light as to what I am missing? Or other hints on how to accomplish this are most welcome.

AzureRM module is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test you need to get individual schedule, not all the schedules in the resource group, it will work in this case:

```
foreach ($azAutAcc in $azAutAccs){
    $AzAutScheds = Get-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $azAutAcc.AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $azAutAcc.ResourceGroupName
    $AzAutScheds = $AzAutScheds | Where-Object {$_.IsEnabled -eq "True"}
    foreach ($AzAutSched in $AzAutScheds){
        $AzAutSched = Get-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $azAutAcc.AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $azAutAcc.ResourceGroupName -Name $AzAutSched.Name
        $DOW = $azAutSched.WeeklyScheduleOptions.DaysOfWeek -join "," | out-string
        $DOM = $azAutSched.MonthlyScheduleOptions.DaysOfMonth -join "," | out-string

        $objs += new-object psobject -Property @{
            SchedName = $AzAutSched.Name
            LastModifiedTime = (get-date ([DateTime]::Parse($AzAutSched.LastModifiedTime)) -Format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm (zzz)")
            IsEnabled = $AzAutSched.IsEnabled
            AutomationAccount = $azAutAcc.AutomationAccountName
            ResourceGroup = $azAutAcc.ResourceGroupName
            NextRun = ([DateTime]::Parse($azAutSched.NextRun))
            StartTime = (get-date ([DateTime]::Parse($azAutSched.StartTime)) -Format "HH:mm (zzz)")
            TimeZone = $azAutSched.TimeZone
            Interval = $azAutSched.Interval
            Frequency = $azAutSched.Frequency
            WeekSchedule = $DOW
            MonthSchedule = $DOM
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for a very swift response :)

Ahhh, I see what I missed now, you are absolutely right. Thanks - this seems to work beautifully, I'll try and work it into my entire script and see what happens :)